# Desvio Padrão diferente com as bibliotecas NUMPY, PANDAS E STATISTICS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Me deparei com o resultado diferente do desvio padrão com as bibliotecas PANDAS e NUMPY, sendo que o dataframe possui o mesmo valor para ambos.

```
numbers = [1, 3.4, 3, 8, 5.5, 6]
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers)
n = np.std(df).round(3)
p = df.std().round(3)
s = statistics.stdev(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois o calculo de desvio padrão do **NUMPY** e do **PANDAS** são diferentes.

Enquanto o **NUMPY** utiliza o calculo de desvio padrão da população padrão (N), a **biblioteca do PANDAS** e a **biblioteca STATISTICS** utilizam o calculo para obter um estimador imparcial para o desvio padrão da população (N-1).

Em estatística o N-1 é chamado de grau de liberdade, subtraindo 1 para obter um estimador imparcial.
Cada fórmula, com ou sem grau de liberdade, depende do tipo de dados que estamos utilizando.
Utilizamos o N-1 para obter um estimador imparcial, e é geralmente por estar lidando com amostras e não populações inteiras.

Porém, podemos alterar o calculo do NUMPY e do PANDAS para adicionar ou remover o grau de liberdade, conforme abaixo:

```
numbers = [1, 3.4, 3, 8, 5.5, 6]
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers)
n = np.std(df).round(3)
n1 = np.std(df, ddof=1) #desvio padrão com grau de liberdade 1 (N-1)
p = df.std().round(3)
p1 = df. std(ddof=0).round(3) #std sem grau de liberdade
s = statistics.stdev(numbers)
```